# CAP theorem: Can I have Consistency and Availability at same time

Tags: computation-theory

Wiki says: one is then left with two options: consistency or availability

Why I cannot get rid of Partition tolerance?

What Partition tolerance actually means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read "Partition Tolerance" as "**Network** Partition Tolerance" and everything will start making sense.

For a distributed system to be reliable, it will always need a form of communication between nodes in different locations (network). You **cannot** get rid of Partition Tolerance (P) because network failure is inevitable.

This does not mean that you cannot aim to have Consistency (C) and Availability (A) for most of the time your system is running, but during a network failure you will need to sacrifice one of them in favor of the other.

See [this post from CodaHale](https://codahale.com/you-cant-sacrifice-partition-tolerance/) for a thorough explanation.